# Sum of same cell (C3) in each available worksheet in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, sum, worksheet-function

I was tried to used this code as i need to sum from second sheet till available sheet in workbook

```
Result = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Worksheets("Second SHEET:FINAL SHEET").Range("C3"))
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are after is the [`Application.Evaluate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.evaluate) method. This gives you the possibility to emulate a calculation like:

```
=SUM('Second Sheet:Final Sheet'!C3)
```

To return the 2nd and last worksheet we can look at the different indexes withing the `WorkSheets` collection and build a valid string to be used in `Evalate`:

```
Sub Test()

With ThisWorkbook
    Dim Nom2d As String: Nom2d = .Worksheets(2).Name
    Dim NomLw As String: NomLw = .Worksheets(.Worksheets.Count).Name
End With

Dim result As Double: result = Evaluate("SUM('" & Nom2d & ":" & NomLw & "'!C3)")

End Sub
```

Provided you haven't tweaked around the `WorkSheets` their indexes, this should do the trick.

---

**EDIT:** If your sheets are actually called `Second SHEET` and `FINAL SHEET`, it's a bit easier:

```
Dim result As Double: result = Evaluate("SUM('Second SHEET:FINAL SHEET'!C3)")
```